# scp command change using alias

Tags: bash, shell, alias, scp

I frequently use

```
scp -r id@remoteserver_ip:/Data_folder/
```

to download data a folder from a remote supercom server.

Having to write the same every time is rather tiresome.

Does anybody know easy to use this command using alias?  Consider that `Data_folder` will be changed every time.

Answer (score 5):

You should consider setting up ssh config:

```
Host myServer
    HostName remoteserver_ip
    User id
```

And perhaps add a [identity file](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html) as well to avoid having to type password:

```
Host myServer
    ...
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_id
```

Now you can write:

```
scp -r myServer:/something
```

Of cause you can - as suggested by other answers - add a function to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
my_scp() {
  scp -r myServer:"$1"
}
```

And then call:

```
my_scp /something
```

Answer (score 3):

Alias can't replace a part of a word. You can create a function, though:

```
myscp () {
    scp -r id@remoteserver_ip:/"$1"/
}
```

Then, just call `myscp Data_folder`.

Also, `scp` (at least on my system) needs the destination folder, too. You can add `.` as then next parameter to the command in the function, or use `"$2"` and specify it on the command line when running the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can't setup an alias to take an argument. So you'll have to create a function and then you'll be able to alias `scp` to that

```
function super_scp() {
    scp -r id@remoteserver_ip:${1} ${2}
}

alias scp=super_scp
```

Then you'll be able to use it like:

```
scp /path/to/folder /destination
```

Comment: Where do you define this function?

Comment: It can be placed in the `.bashrc` file so that it's automatically sourced on login.

Comment: aliases in bashrc is not quite recommended mate :P It would be better to do aliases in bash_profile ot create bash_aliases

Comment: It doesn't really matter as long as you source it from your `.bash_profile` for non-interactive mode.

Comment: You are totaly right! but I don't really like adding aliases to bashrc because it will make the file so big for nothing! Here http://askubuntu.com/questions/194111/how-save-my-alias-entries-forever# they recommand sourcing bash_aliases to bashrc :)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a bash file in one of your $PATH folders.

```
#! /bin/bash
scp -r id@remoteserver_ip:"$1" "$2"
```

Let's call the script myscp.

Instead of writing the whole line you wrote, you can write

```
myscp /home/file.txt /home/file2.txt
```